# Background Removal from Images

Tags: api, camera

Are there any open source APIs out there can can remove a background from an image automatically as soon as a photo is taken?

Answer (score 3):

To remove the background from an image you need an image processing or computer vision library.

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) offers a lot of functionality to manipulate images and offers libraries for iOS and Android.

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html) is an example of how a background subtraction can be achieved.

There are also other possibilities to achieve this.

For iOS i found an example using Quartz2D (*Masking an Image with Color*):
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html

and for Android:
https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/image-processing-pixel-color-replacement/

Answer (score 3):

There is this program, https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover which is free and open source, and you can install via pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install backgroundremover
```

Then just script it to do

```
backgroundremover -i "/path/to/image.jpeg" -o "output.png"
```

source: author of the project

Answer (score 2):

[Remove.bg](https://www.remove.bg/) Seems to work really well. For free you can get 50 calls per months, you have to pay if you want more.